# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(m-k)x^{m-k-1}$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(m-k)x^{m-k-1}$

Tags: problem-solving

If I have $y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{m-k}$ ,then is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(m-k)x^{m-k-1}$ correct because ..I'm confused whether $k$ should start from $0$ or from $1$.

Please explain..